# Kafka docker - ERROR: "Unable to find leader for partition 0"

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, docker-swarm

Below is part of my YML file for zookeeper and Kafka Dockers 
Ive added "KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS" variable to create topics at startup
but it takes long time to create all 6 topics. so every time I bring dockers down and up, I need to wait untill all topics created 
*the solution to create topics by kafkaProducer is not good for me 
 
when kafka/zookeeper are up, I want them to remember all topics so I added volumes to Zookeeper, it worked and now topic exist on startup, but I cannot consume any topic because I get the following ERROR: 
"Unable to find leader for partition 0"

```
      zoo1:
    image: xx.xx.xx.xx:5002/zookeeper
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
    networks:
      - xxnet  
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition:  on-failure 
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: 50m 
    volumes:    
      - /home/docker-volumes/zoo1-conf/:/conf
      - /home/docker-volumes/zoo1-data/:/data
      - /home/docker-volumes/zoo1-datalog/:/datalog


  kafka:
    image: xx.xx.xx.xx:5002/wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092

    environment:
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: xx.xx.xx.xx
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: 1600000
        #KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=true
        KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 0
        KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MINUTES: 0
        KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS: 120000
        RETENTION.MS: 900000
        ADVERTISED_HOST: kafkaserver
        ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
        KAFKA_SEGMENT_BYTES: 1073741824
        KAFKA_RETENTION_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS: 300000
        KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: topic1:1:1,topic2:1:1,topic3:1:1,topic4:1:1,topic5:1:1,topic6:1:1


    networks:
      - xxnet   
    volumes: 
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
     - /home/docker-volumes/kafka-logs/:/tmp/kafka-logs
     - /home/docker-volumes/kafka-logs/kafka:/kafka
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition:  on-failure     
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: 50m
```

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Please read https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Not sure what the ENV variable ZOO_SERVERS does or how it is interpreted but if the number after the container identifier is port and that too internal and external port then for sure the brokers cannot connect to the zookeeper since the ports are not exposed..

Comment: everything work fine if I remove the Zookeeper Volume except it not remember my Topics if I remove those volumes. and if I keep Volumes, topics exist but I cant consume them (as described on question)

Comment: any idea? someone?